# How to determine where a open_basedir restriction is coming from

Tags: php, mediawiki

We are trying to upgrade to Mediawiki 1.30 through Mediawiki's release tarball. `upgrade.php` is failing because the release tarball is missing components (for example, *`PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Wikimedia\Assert\Assert' not found`*).

If I am parsing things correctly, it looks like we have to set the web server up as a developer machine. We installed composer, symphony and its 33 dependencies according to [Upgraded to MediaWiki 26 alpha, missing Assert](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30681618/608639).

Attempting to run composer results in a *`open_basedir restriction in effect...`* error (see below). We are now trying to figure out where the restriction is coming from. According to [How to set for specific directory open_basedir](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13291185/608639), it is `httpd.conf`, `php.ini` or a `.htaccess` file.

The problem is, none of our configuration files have the restriction:

```
# find /etc -name php.ini -exec cat {} \; | grep open_basedir
; open_basedir, if set, limits all file operations to the defined directory
;open_basedir =
# find /opt/rh -name php.ini -exec cat {} \; | grep open_basedir
; open_basedir, if set, limits all file operations to the defined directory
;open_basedir =
# find /etc -name httpd.conf -exec cat {} \; | grep open_basedir
# find /opt/rh -name httpd.conf -exec cat {} \; | grep open_basedir
# find /var/www/html -name .htaccess -exec cat {} \; | grep open_basedir
```

I have two questions. First, is there a way to get a release tarball with everything that is needed to run the software?

Second, if a release tarball is not available, then how do we determine where the configuration is coming from?

---

```
# cd /var/www/html/wiki
# composer update
PHP Warning:  require(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/php/Composer/autoload.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/html/:/var/www/html/w/:/var/lib/php/session/) in /usr/bin/composer on line 9
PHP Warning:  require(/usr/share/php/Composer/autoload.php): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /usr/bin/composer on line 9
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/usr/share/php/Composer/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/rh/rh-php71/root/usr/share/pear:/opt/rh/rh-php71/root/usr/share/php') in /usr/bin/composer on line 9
```

Answer (score 1):

open_basedir errors are common with PHP and not necessarily specific to mediawiki. open_basedir is set in php.ini. Try installing [mlocate](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-mlocate-locate-and-updatedb-commands-on-centos-7/) and then run: `locate php.ini`

If none of the php.ini files explicitly have open_basedir set, it may be using default values so try manually adding it anyway, including your existing path, and then restarting your web server i.e.:

```
open_basedir = ".:/opt/rh/rh-php71/root/usr/share/pear:/opt/rh/rh-php71/root/usr/share/php:/usr/share/php/Composer/"
```